# Only one string from a set of data is not getting saved on firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, oncreate, android-viewholder

I'm trying to save a set of data under a single `pushID` on firebase. I have made a model class which has all the string which should get saved.

Here is the model class:

```
public class GModelClass extends AbstractItem<GModelClass, GModelClass.ViewHolder>{

    String postedBy, postedTime, currentLat, currentLng, utcFormatDateTime, userEmail;
    public static String userID;

    public GModelClass(){}

    public GModelClass(String postedBy, String postedTime, String currentLat, String currentLng, String utcFormatDateTime, String userEmail, String userID) {
        this.postedBy = " " + postedBy;
        this.postedTime = postedTime;
        this.currentLat = currentLat;
        this.currentLng = currentLng;
        this.utcFormatDateTime = utcFormatDateTime;
        this.userEmail = userEmail;
        this.userID = userID;
    }

    @Override
    public int getType() {
        return R.id.recycler_view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getLayoutRes() {
        return R.layout.game_requests_layout;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(ViewHolder holder, List list) {
        super.bindView(holder, list);

        holder.postedBy.setText(postedBy);
        holder.postedBy.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        holder.postedTime.setText(postedTime);
        holder.userID.setText(userID);

    }

    // Manually create the ViewHolder class
    protected static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView postedBy, postedTime, userEmail, currentLatitude, currentLongitude, utcFormatDateTime, formattedTime, userID;

        public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            postedBy = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.postedBy);
            postedTime = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.postedTime);
            userID = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.userID);
        }
    }

}
```

Here's the method:

```
public void postedNewGRequest(String postedBy, String postedTime, String currentLat, String currentLng, String utcFormatDateTime, String userEmail, String userID) {
        GModelClass gModelClass = new GModelClass(postedBy, postedTime, currentLat, currentLng, utcFormatDateTime, userEmail, userID);
        mDatabase.child(itemID).setValue(gModelClass);
    }
```

AND THEN I'M CALLING `postedNewGameRequest()` IN `onButtonClickListener()` like this to save the data on firebase:

```
postedNewGRequest(MainActivity.name, time, currentLat.getText().toString(), currentLng.getText().toString(), utcFormatDateTime, MainActivity.email, MainActivity.uid);
```

What is happening is all the data is getting saved in firebase except 'MainActivity.uid' (in model class it is 'userID') and I don't know why!

Please let me know.

Comment: Hi use toMap() in your GModelClass, it will save all the mapped values in database.

Comment: can you explain it more clearly, please?

Comment: Hi follow up this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/save-data)

Comment: @JayVignesh 's comment solved the problem.